# C++ Trying to call a method with class that is derived from other class

Tags: c++, polymorphism, derived-class

Hi so I recently tried to create sort of a Filters for a Database which must meet specific Criteria. I am sort of a amateur when it comes to C++ Polymorfism. So I really don't know Where is problem anymore.

Kriterium.h Header ->

```
//Kriterium.h 

#pragma once
#include "Uzemna_Jednotka.h"
#include "Politicke_Strany.h"

template <typename O, typename T>
class Kriterium
{
public:
    Kriterium() {};
    virtual T ohodnot( O& pObject) = 0;
    virtual ~Kriterium() {};
};
template <typename T>
class KriteriumUJ : public Kriterium<Uzemna_Jednotka, T> {
public:
    KriteriumUJ() {};
    virtual T ohodnot( Uzemna_Jednotka& pJednotka) = 0;
    virtual ~KriteriumUJ() {};
};


class KriteriumPatriDo : public KriteriumUJ<bool> {
public:
    KriteriumPatriDo() : KriteriumUJ() {};
    bool ohodnot( Uzemna_Jednotka& pJednotka)  override  { return pJednotka.checkIFPatriDoVUC(aVyssiCelok); };
    void setVyssiCelok(Uzemna_Jednotka* pJednotka)  { aVyssiCelok = pJednotka; };
    Uzemna_Jednotka* getVyssiCelok()  { return aVyssiCelok; };
    ~KriteriumPatriDo() {};
private:
    Uzemna_Jednotka* aVyssiCelok;


};
```

Filter.h Header ->

```
//Filter

#pragma once
#include "Kriterium.h"
#include "Uzemna_Jednotka.h"
#include "structures/heap_monitor.h"
#include "structures/table/sorted_sequence_table.h"
#include "structures/table/unsorted_sequence_table.h"


template<typename O, typename T, typename H> 
class Filter
{
public:
    Filter() {};

    virtual UnsortedSequenceTable<H, O> vyfiltruj(UnsortedSequenceTable<H, O> pVstup, Kriterium<O, T>& pKriterium) = 0;

protected:

    virtual bool splnaFilter(O& pObject, Kriterium<O,T>& pKriterium) = 0;

private:



};


template<typename O, typename T, typename H>
class Filter_fi : public Filter<O, T, H>
{
public:
    Filter_fi() {};
    void setAlpha(T pAlpha) { alphaPARAM = pAlpha; };
    T getAlpha() { return alphaPARAM; };

    UnsortedSequenceTable<H, O> vyfiltruj(UnsortedSequenceTable<H, O> pVstup, Kriterium<O, T>& pKriterium) override
    {
        UnsortedSequenceTable<H, O>* table = new UnsortedSequenceTable<H, O>;
        for (TableItem<H, O>* prem : pVstup) {
            if (splnaFilter(prem->accessData(), pKriterium)) {
                table->insert(prem->getKey(), prem->accessData());
            }

        }
        return *table;
    };



    virtual ~Filter_fi() {};

protected:
    virtual bool splnaFilter(O& pObject, Kriterium<O, T>& pKriterium) override { return pKriterium.ohodnot(pObject) == alphaPARAM; };
private:

    T alphaPARAM;

};

template<typename O, typename T, typename H>
class Filter_FI : public Filter<O, T, H>
{
public:
    Filter_FI() {};



    void setParametre(T pMin, T pMax) { aMin = pMin, aMax = pMax; };
    T getMin() { return aMin; };
    T getMax() { return aMax; };

    UnsortedSequenceTable<H, O> vyfiltruj(UnsortedSequenceTable<H, O> pVstup, Kriterium<O, T>& pKriterium) override
    {
        UnsortedSequenceTable<H, O>* table = new UnsortedSequenceTable<H, O>;
        for (TableItem<H, O>* prem : pVstup) {
            if (splnaFilter(prem->accessData(), pKriterium)) {
                table->insert(prem->getKey(), prem->accessData());
            }

        }
        return *table;
    };





    virtual ~Filter_FI() {};

protected:
    virtual bool splnaFilter(O& pObject, Kriterium<O, T>& pKriterium) override {

        T hodnota = pKriterium.ohodnot(pObject);
        return (aMin <= hodnota && hodnota <= aMax);

    };
    //Kriterium<O, T>* aKriterium;

private:
    T aMin;
    T aMax;


};


class Filter_UJ_Prislusnost : public Filter_fi <Uzemna_Jednotka*, bool, int> {
public:
    Filter_UJ_Prislusnost():  Filter_fi() {};
    virtual ~Filter_UJ_Prislusnost() {};

};
```

*The problem is if I try to call ->

```
aFilter_Typ.setAlpha(UzemnaJednotka_TYP_Enum::Obec);
    aFilter_Typ.vyfiltruj(aTabulkaUJ, aKriterium);
```

-> aKriterium gives a

```
C++ a reference of type (not const-qualified) cannot be    initialized with a value of type
```

```
 [![Description of the Error][1]][1]

Filter and Kriterium are initialized like this ->
```

```
    Filter_UJ_Name aFilter_Meno;
    KriteriumPatriDo aKriterium;
```

I would be very glad if you could help me fix the problem.*

Comment: I tried to also include the image of the problem, but it sort of didn't worked. So here it is : https://imgur.com/a/uxzGBbR

Comment: It would be quite helpful if you could edit your question to instead have a minimum reproducible example. Right now, you have a lot of code that is hard to parse through and not relevant to the question.

Comment: What is a `KriteriumPatriDo`?

Comment: @Beta Edited it a bit. I tried to minimize the code. And I mistakenly posted wrong class there. `KriteriumPatriDo` Should be there now.

Comment: What is a `Filter_UJ_Name`? What is `aFilter_Typ`? Please read the page on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you for your help. After many hours I figured out that I mistakenly tried to pass out a different type of parameter. But I found out after your comment. Thank you anyway.